# Custom Segmented Control in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to implement a segmented control but it seems so simple in the layout. I want to customize it:

- lose the borders for instance
- have a custom indicator

What would be the way to do it? I know in Android how to customise an TabLayout but here I'm lost to be honest.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm quite late to the party, but here's what I'd do:

Set the background color to .clear

```
    segmentedControlInstance.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.16, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0)
```

Set the background tint color to .clear

```
    segmentedControlInstance.tintColor = .clear
```

I noticed the selected segment's title is bold. Set the text attributes for the two states (.normal & .selected)

```
    segmentedControlInstance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)], for: .normal)
    segmentedControlInstance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)], for: .selected)
```

Finally, set the two background images. Caution, I have no idea what to set for the barMetrics parameter:

```
     segmentedControlInstance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(name: "selectedSegment", for: .selected, barMetrics: ?)
     segmentedControlInstance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(name: "normalSegment", for: .normal, barMetrics: ?)
```

I'll let you play around with the barMetrics parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If what I need to customize wasn't on this list, [UISegmentedControl Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol#1653545), I'd build my own.

In your image, I'd use two buttons, a view for the indicator, and some logic to respond to user interactions.